# What does "no words far away" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

Today I heard the song of "Over and over" sung by Nana Mouskouri. By the way, I don't understand one phrase in the lyrics. That is "Here in your arms, no words far away". What does "no words far away" mean?

Comment: It's not an idiomatic phrase (though the two halves _no words_ and _far away_ are). As a native English speaker, I have no idea what it means - perhaps if I heard more of the song I could make some sense of it.

Comment: Could l ask you for answering after reading the entire lyrics of the song? Please.

Comment: @Colin   Could I ask you for answering after reading the entire lyrics of the song? I am afraid my asking would hurt your mind.

Comment: If you ask people to do that, you really need to provide a link to the full lyric rather than expecting everyone to look it up for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation helps. It seems to be:

> Here in your arms. No words. Far away.

It means, **In your embrace. Without speaking. Dreamy**.

Clearly she's not *literally* far away from the person who's embracing her. So I think the adjective **faraway** is intended:

> **faraway:** Seeming remote from the immediate surroundings; dreamy.

[Definition 1.1 here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/faraway).

Comment: Your explanation helps so much. But if the lyrics on the google is correct,  it is not "no words. Far away" but " no words far away. Even if so', your answer is available?

Comment: But "no words far away" means "all words within easy reach": a good advertisement for a dictionary, but out of place in the song. Lyrics are often ungrammatical and wrongly punctuated and we often advise people not to try and learn English from songs. What do you mean "available?" I found the lyrics [here](https://www.flashlyrics.com/lyrics/nana-mouskouri/over-and-over-71), if that's what you mean.

Comment: Lyrics on web sites are often badly typed and may contain missing punctuation.